# $x = 3$ in $\Bbb Z_5$ equivalent to saying $x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I basically want to confirm the title, if I wrote both of these in a test it'd be considered the same, right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @WillFisher The correct notation is the OP's $\ x\equiv 3\pmod 5.\ $ Your notation  $\ x\equiv 3\mod 5\,$ is not correct and often causes beginners to confuse relational vs. operational mod.

Answer (score 2):

If one accepts that

$\Bbb Z / (5) \equiv \Bbb Z_5, \tag 1$

then it is evident that

$x = 3 \in \Bbb Z_5 = \Bbb Z / (5) \tag 2$

means that

$x \in 3 + (5), \tag 3$

that is,

$x - 3 = 5n, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag 4$

i.e.,

$x \equiv 3 \pmod 5. \tag 5$

If I were grading the test I would accept either notation as correct.